# Find a basis of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V = $\mathbb{R}^4$ I'm trying to find the intersection of the following subspaces of V:
$U = \{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x-2y+z-t = 0\}$

$W = \{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x+y+z+t = 0\}$

I've got that the basis of $U\cap W$ is $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,-2/3,0,1), (0,0,1,0)\}$. How is that possible? it implies that $\dim U\cap W = 3$, but $\dim U = 3$ and $\dim W = 3$. Doesn't that imply that $U$ must be equal $W$ (which I don't think is true here)?

Also, I found that the basis of U is $\{(1,0,0,1),(0,1,0,2),(0,0,1,1)\}$, and surely for every vector in $U\cap W$ is also in $U$, but for $(1,0,0,0) \in U \cap W$, you can't find any linear combination of the basis of $U$ such that it equals $(1,0,0,0)$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: For anyone interested, my mistake was thinking that $U \cap W = \{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R} \mid  x−2y+z−t = x + y + z +t\}$, and disregarded the fact that the vectors also must be in $U$ and $W$, and thus meet their requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $U \cap W$ you want those vectors which satisfy
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&1&-1&|&0\\
1&1&1&1&|&0
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&1&-1&|&0\\
0&3&0&2&|&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus the solution set is
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\t
\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}
-z-t/3\\-2t/3\\z\\t
\end{bmatrix}
=t\begin{bmatrix}
-1/3\\-2/3\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus $U \cap W$ is spanned by two vectors listed above, implying that $\text{Dim}(U \cap W)=2$

**Comments:**

1. The vector $(1,0,0,0)$ is in neither space. So it cannot be in a basis set of any spaces mentioned in the question.
2. Just because the dimensions of two spaces is same doesn't mean that they have to be the same (think any two straight lines passing through the origin with different slopes).

Comment: Can you please explain how, in the first expression you wrote on the table on the right, how did you get the second row (0,3,0,2)?

Comment: @blz I used row operations to row reduce the matrix $-R_1+R_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you proceed a little further, you obtain explicitly the coefficients in the matrix. Note, as this is a homogeneous linear system, you don't need to use the augmented matrix. This, using row reduction to obtain the *reduced* row echelon form, we have the following steps:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&-1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&-1\\0&3&0&2\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&-1\\0&1&0&2/3\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0\hspace{-0.3em}&\vdots\hspace{-0.3em}&1&1/3\\0&1\hspace{-0.3em}&\vdots\hspace{-0.3em}&0&2/3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Hence the parametric representation of the plane is
$$\begin{cases}x=-z-\dfrac t3\\y=-\dfrac{2t}3\end{cases}\iff\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=-z\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}-\frac t3\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$
Setting successively $z=-1, t=0$, then $z=0, t=-3$, we obtain the basis:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\\-3\end{bmatrix}.$$